# 550 Access Denied when copying web pages from Visual Web Developer 2008 to somee.com

Tags: asp.net

I have created a website on Visual Web Developer and created an account on somee.com as a FTP web host, but when I use Visual Web Developer to copy my webpage aspx files, none of my aspx files get copied and it gives me a messagebox saying that "There were errors during web copy. Please view log for details". I view the log and it says:

> Copy file calculator.aspx from source to remote Web site.
>               Has error -- Unable to add 'calculator.aspx' to the Web site.  550 Access is denied.

I tried the same thing for Filezilla, but it give me this:

```
Status: Resolving address of www.pvhsgpa.somee.com
Status: Connecting to 66.197.198.216:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER antlowhur
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS *******************
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\dlowhur\Documents\Visual Studio 
2008\WebSites\WebSite1\calculator.aspx
Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 CWD command successful.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (66,197,198,216,192,218).
Command:    STOR calculator.aspx
Response:   550 Access is denied. 
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

I also turned off firewall, so I don't think there is a problem with that. Any suggestions on fixing this error?

Comment: Your host isn't letting you write.

Comment: How do I get permission to let my host write?

Comment: Contact your host and ask them.